# The understanding of syntax of a simple probability question

Tags: probability

I am reading a book about probability and statistics. But I have question about understanding of the sentence of "There is a 30 percent chance that it does not rain either day". I translate this sentence to P(Ac ∪ Bc)=0.3 which lead my answer completed different from the correct answer.  The answer translates the third sentence to P(Ac ∩ Bc)=0.3. Since English is my second language, I am confused the wording about this sentence.

I checked on the dictionary about the meaning. In question, what should be the correct meaning?  Or I misunderstood this sentence? I am Ok with the question itself. Thank you!

```
 Either:
 1 : being the one and the other of two 
 2 : being the one or the other of two


Suppose we have the following information:

There is a 60 percent chance that it will rain today.
There is a 50 percent chance that it will rain tomorrow.
There is a 30 percent chance that it does not rain either day.

Find the following probabilities:
The probability that it will rain today or tomorrow.
The probability that it will rain today and tomorrow.
The probability that it will rain today but not tomorrow.
The probability that it either will rain today or tomorrow, but not both.
```

Comment: It means that it does not rain on day 1 **and** it does not rain on day 2.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is correct. The expression *it does not rain either day* means there is no rain on the first day **and** there is no rain on the second day.

Hence, if $A$ denotes raining on the first day and $B$ - on the second day, you have
$$
\bar{A} \cap \bar{B},
$$
as in the answer

Comment: So the sentence can be translated into "the probability of it does not rain on both days is 0.3. In here, either is same as both. Am I correct?   Thank you!

Comment: @Steve Yes, "it does not rain on both days" means a similar thing